# how to create const int** from int**

Tags: c, constants, double-pointer

Is there way to create an const int** from an int**?

I'm currently using:

`const int **pixel2=*pixel;`

`const char **header2=*header;`

I keep getting the error: `cscd240HW34.c:52:21: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  const int **pixel2=*pixel;`

Comment: What are `pixel` and `header`? Normally, a simple cast is good enough.

Comment: pixel is an int** used to store a set of pixel intensity values, header is the stuff before the values

Comment: Wouldn't it be `const int **pixel2 = pixel;` then?

Comment: @Kninnug I still get the same error

Comment: Did you read what I said? "Normally, a simple cast is good enough."

Comment: @Cornstalks, I misread what you wrote. Thank you also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pixel` is already of type `int **` then:

```
const int **pixel2 = (const int **)pixel;
```

By way of explanation: the reason a cast is required is because this still doesn't give you as much type-safety as you might think. For example you could now write:

```
const int c = 'x';
*pixel2 = &c;    // fine, both are const int *
**pixel = 'y';   // no compiler error, but UB as we modify a non-writable object
```

So, see if there is another way to do what you want to do.  Note that this definition of `pixel2` avoids that exploit

```
const int * const * pixel2;
```

although sadly C still requires a cast to assign `pixel` to `pixel2`.

This question is 11.10 in the c.l.c. FAQ.

Comment: Thanks! No more error

Comment: Do not suppress errors with type casts, and do not teach others to suppress errors with type casts.

Comment: This isn't an error per se

Comment: @n.m.: Then how do you purpose this be done? I've worked with libraries that required a `const T**`, while I have a `T**`. If you know how to do this without a cast, please, do share.

Comment: So is this a bad thing to do?

Comment: added more explanation

Comment: +1 for the added info.

Comment: `int** ppi; const int* pci = *ppi; const int** ppci = &pci;` (`const T**` is almost always wrong and if you are stuck with a broken interface you may have to do casts, but you should know very well what exactly is broken, and what exactly you are doing to fix it.)

Comment: Are there any casts other than C-style casts, in C? :)

Comment: `int const * const *pixel2 = (int const * const *)pixel` is perfectly safe AFAICS. It's not ideal to use a cast as you say, but having to introduce a dummy variable just to avoid the cast is also not ideal.